# Testing Angular, loading template before loading data

Tags: javascript, angular, selenium, testing

I have an angular 11 website that I wish to write automated tests for. The issue I'm having is that all the templates/fields/labels/inputs etc load first. Then the data is fetched from the database using a GET method. This creates a problem since the tests wait for an input element to appear, the element appears. The test starts writing "hello world" into that input. The web then finished fetching the data from the backend. and overwrites "hello world".

I don't understand how I can wait for the GET request to finish since that information is hidden from Selenium.

What i've tried so far. but this just waits for the element but not the data:

```
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 25)
    element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, user_name_id)
    wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable(By.CSS_SELECTOR, user_name_id)
    element.send_keys(text)
```

Comment: Can you please share the code what have you tried?

Comment: @NandanA Sure i've tried most waits with selenium. I post an example. the waits do work FOR THE ELEMENT but not for the data.

Comment: You need wait until API returns a response then proceed with selenium  steps?

Comment: Yes, the web communicates with the backend. But from Selenium I can't access the call.

Comment: When it returns response any attribute value changes or any attribute gets added to the HTML?

Comment: If I am understanding it correctly, you can wait for any value to appear on page.

Comment: @QualityMatters So the only way is if I know the data before hand?

Comment: not the data, the presence of data.

Comment: @QualityMatters what if the data is none? so say you have an input element called "nickname" some users have one some don't

Comment: Just ask your developers to add a page loader element until the page loads. Check that loader presence in your automation if for all fields you have such doubts. One more thing, check the API calls in your web application. In real world, API's dont take so much time to send data to UI, else who will use that application.